# Return PHP data back to my current webpage for Javascript to access

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a form which users will submit to my WordPress website, and with that data I will create a post. The form submission is done with AJAX so the page does not reload. I have the post ID that I need to pass back onto the page so the Javascript can POST more data to that specific post.

How can I pass the post ID, which is just a integer, back to the page so I can keep editing that post?

Comment: Echo the post id.  Show us the code and we can help a little more.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to use AJAX. It's impossible for PHP code to pass variables directly to Javascript without a page load, since PHP is server sided (parsed before page load) and Javascript is client sided (parsed after/during page load).

My suggestion: Make a script that retrieves post IDs, for example "pid.php". Then simply get the contents of that page with AJAX and convert to integer form with `parseInt` for Javascript.

EDIT: As Austin so wisely suggested, you could also use json.

Comment: That gives me a much better idea of where to take this, thank you.

Comment: You should not parseInt client side... Much less error prone if you use PHP function json_encode that is made just for this.

Comment: No problem @atesc, just trying to help out around here more.

Answer (score 0):

After a successful ajax request, save the post id to a global variable so It can be used later.

**For example**
Client side:

```
var post_id = 0; //use the post id later to edit the same post.

$.ajax({
  url: 'somefile.php',
  success: function(data) {
    alert('success, post id is: ' + data.id);
    post_id = data.id;
  }
});
```

Server side:

```
$post_id = 123;

echo json_encode(array('id' => $post_id));
```

Comment: Albeit a valid answer, i do not see jQuery mentioned anywhere in the original question.